# Problem using motion paths to move multiple objects in Expression Blend

Tags: expression-blend

I have a requirement where in I have to move four objects on an elliptical path.
Am using Expression Blend and was able to create a motion path quite very easily and place objects over it. It was also cool creating storyboards and keyframes.

The problem came when i wanted all the objects to move at once, their starting points being different. I mean I want the sarting point of each object to be different.

I have searched for answers but could find people ending up in creating their own custom paths through code behind.

Is there a way that we could achieve this through Expression Blend?

Thanks in advance,
Sri

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do, exactly?  If you are creating a Storyboard, why not just give each object a different starting location?  If you are trying to create a Carousel or something like that, check out PathListBox.  If neither of these are helpful, post some more specifics.